# Red and White Squares

Tags: logical-deduction, strategy, optimization

There are two grid boards with the dimension of 9x9 and 14x14, consist of all white squares. You are supposed to color some squares with a red color on the conditions below:

- In a board, if two square has a common edge, they are neighbor squares.
- Every square needs to have at least 2 colored neighbor squares (excluding itself)

so

> **What is the least number of red squares you can have with the condition above?**

Comment: The lower bound for 9x9 is 41 and for 14x14 is 98 , right ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer for $14 \times 14$ is

> $112$

Achieved as follows

> [image]

While the best I've achieved for $9 \times 9$ is

> $50$

Achieved as follows

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

For $14$x$14$ I got...

> $112$

With this ...

> [image]

Or with this...

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume

> the boards are independent

Then one solution would be

> 171 red squares.

As shown below

> [image]
>  for 51 squares

And

> [image]
>  for 120 squares

No idea if this is minimal though

Comment: I think that for example cell x=9,y=14 doesn't have to be red

Answer (score -1):

9*9 solution:

> 45 reds

Looks like:

> [image]

14*14 solution:

> 110 reds

Looks like:

> [image]

Comment: In your 9x9, there are eight red squares only adjacent to one red square and the one in the centre is adjacent to none. In your 14 x 14, the two red squares in the centre are adjacent to no red squares,

Comment: Oh crap, apologies, I thought that the rule was that all white squares needed to be adjacent to two red squares